# How to pass context value to init method of any pivot in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to call a pivot from wizard by passing `date range` parameters to it, but i am unable to pass value to `init` method of `pivot` or suggest me any other way to pass `date range` to `pivot`.

Please Help me about it, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: You are creating a report using a SQL view? and why you want to pass data range? to filter records?

Comment: Yes exactly.. do have any idea .

Comment: You shouldn't do that can you post your cod?

Comment: I want to do same in this `https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-fetch-context-value-from-wizard-to-pivot-view-153101` answers , but not able to do in odoo8